# Sorting records by dates represented as tuples

Tags: haskell, quicksort

I am trying to make a function that sorts a List of Person (which is a tuple of (Name, Date), whereby date is a tuple of (Int, Int, Int) in the Form DD,MM,YYYY) by the Date.

I made the following:

I made little functions getThrd, getSnd and getFst to extract the Year-, Month- and Day-value out of the tuple respectively. Then I used quicksort to sort the List first by Year.

```
quickSortYear :: [Person] -> [Person]
quickSortYear [] = []
quickSortYear (x:xs) = quickSortYear [y |y<-xs, (getThrd y)>(getThrd x)]++[x]++[y|y<-xs, (getThrd y)<=(getThrd x)]
```

Then I made sortMonth and sortDay functions, which go through the sorted-by-year List and sort by Month and Day, one after another, as in the final sortNameList function.

```
sortMonth :: [Person] -> [Person]
sortMonth (x:y:xs)
    |(getThrd x)==(getThrd y) && (getSnd x)>(getSnd y) = x : sortMonth (y:xs)
    |(getThrd x)==(getThrd y) && (getSnd x)<(getSnd y) = y : sortMonth (x:xs)
    |(getThrd x)==(getThrd y) && (getSnd x)==(getSnd y) = x : y : sortMonth (xs)
    |(getThrd x)/=(getThrd y) = x : y : (sortMonth xs)

sortDay :: [Person] -> [Person]
sortDay (x:y:xs)
    |(getThrd x)==(getThrd y) && (getSnd x)==(getSnd y) && (getFst x)>(getSnd y) = x : sortDay (y:xs)
    |(getThrd x)==(getThrd y) && (getSnd x)==(getSnd y) && (getFst x)<(getSnd y) = y : sortDay (x:xs)
    |(getThrd x)==(getThrd y) && (getSnd x)==(getSnd y) && (getFst x)==(getSnd y) = x : y : sortDay (xs)
    |(getThrd x)/=(getThrd y) || (getSnd x)/=(getSnd y) = x : y : (sortDay xs)

sortNameList :: [Person] -> [Person]
sortNameList (x:xs) = sortDay(sortMonth(quickSortYear (x:xs)))
```

The idea was to let sortNameList to first sort by year, then let sortMonth run over the sorted list and sort what it can by month and then let sortDay run through the sorted list and sort what it can.

I have no parsing errors.
But when I test it with a list, it says that the pattern is non-exhaustive in sortMonth.

When I tested sortMonth and sortDay each by themselves, both gave the non-exhaustive pattern error.

I looked throgh my code many times and I don't understand why it won't work.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you supply a list with one or no element to either `sortDay` or `sortMonth`? Your pattern `(x:y:xs)` only matches lists with at least *two* elements.

That being said, your current code is a little bit cumbersome, isn't it? Try to write the following function:

```
quickSortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Then you can express `sortMonth` and `sortDay` easily. Note that `quickSortBy` already exists as `sortBy` in `Data.List`, so use that one if you managed to write `quickSortBy`.